# Как сделать открытый доступ к WebSockets серверу всем пользователям сайта?

Tags: javascript, сервер, websocket

Написал сервер и клиент WebSockets в JS фалах, разместил все на хостинге. Необходимо чтобы все пользователи имели возможность взаимодействовать с сервером. Во всех обучающих видео и примерах в адресе сервера я видел только "ws://localhost:8081" или что-то подобное с "localhost". 
Как я понимаю, это локальное подключение. Вопрос, что нужно написать чтобы с сервером могли взаимодействовать все удаленные пользователи? Может быть, есть какое-нибудь видео?

Answer (score 0):

ну для начала определите домен в сети для сокетов, также лучше поставить на него ssl и ваш адрес к подключению будет примерно таким wss://your_domain.com:8081 и затем вы определяете сокет канал, в который и шлете события (неважно откуда), а пользователи, которым он нужен должны "подписаться на этот канал" иными словами его слушать (в подключении должны указать адрес и порт до вашего сервера (wss://your_domain.com:8081) и слушать либо один канал, либо все и сразу) и уже писать свои обработчики на приход событий

Comment: Спасибо. Но вот как определить домен в сети для сокетов?

Comment: подключаем socket.io библиотеку 

`let host;

let port = '7777';


host = 'https://ws.your_domain.com';

window.io = require('socket.io-client')(host + ':' + port);`

И затем слушаем какой-нибудь канал (пример ниже)

`var configSocketChannel = '{{config("app.socket_channel")}}';

    io.on('chat:GeneralSend{{config("app.socket_channel")}}', function (data) {

        //выполняем свои действия

    });`

P.S. Подключение указано с синтаксисом ES6, дернуто из моего проекта, но суть не меняется